# QBO3 Attachment/Generate is called,but Attachment/Download fails

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Using the QBO3 Import framework, we are generating a mail-merge document using this XML snippet:

```
<AttachmentItem Operation="Generate">
  <Object>ImportForm</Object>
  <ObjectSubscriberID>CRLetterCycle-17010353-2442587</ObjectSubscriberID>
  <Template>CR CFPB RET Ack Incomplete Appl</Template>
</AttachmentItem>
```

and in the results, we see:

```
<Result ID="1816859">
  <Object>Attachment</Object>
  <ObjectID>524624</ObjectID>
  <Operation>Insert</Operation>
  <Status>Success</Status>
  <Properties>
    ... [omitted for brevity] ...
  </Properties>
</Result>
```

However, when we attempt to download the merged document by calling:

```
Attachment/Download?ID=524624
```

we get and HTTP 500 error, with a response that contains:

> The specified file was not found in the '[...]' file object
>   repository. Parameter name: relativePath Actual value was
>   qboRoot/ImportForm/1633788/CRLetter.b6e893b7-552e-4298-9495-eaa0fb4e6a34.pdf.

Why do we get a success indicator in the import results, but cannot download the generated file?

Answer (score 0):

When the QBO3 Import Framework processes the XML you provided, there are two method signatures executed:

- `Attachment/Insert`, and
- `Attachment/Generate`

If you inspect your import results XML a bit more, you'll find two nodes related to your attachments; the one you noted in your question, and a second one:

```
<Result ID="1816860">
  <Object>Attachment</Object>
  <ObjectID>524624</ObjectID>
  <Status>Error</Status>
  <Message>Invalid column name 'Item'. [Omitted for brevity]</Message>
  <Source>.Net SqlClient Data Provider</Source>
</Result>
```

In short, the `Attachment/Insert` worked, creating an Attachment row in the database, but the `Attachment/Generate` errored, failing to save an actual mail-merged file to disk.

The error rendered in the import results is also logged in the ImportLog table, viewable (and reportable) from:

- Design > Import Data > {Imported XML file}